# Convert Hex code to Date (BLE) - Algorithm

Tags: ios, swift

Sample dates and Corresponding Hex-codes

```
min: 01-Jan-2001 00:00:00 -> Hex code 00 00 00 00
max: 31-Dec-2099 23:59:59 -> Hex code BA 36 8E 7F

Value 0 reckons to 01-Jan-2001 00:00:00 Offset value for UNIX Timestamp: 978307200
```

How to convert the given hex code to date as per the same pattern?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The data is the big-endian representation of the date offset to the
“reference date” (00:00:00 UTC on 1 January 2001):

```
let data = Data(bytes: [0xBA, 0x36, 0x8E, 0x7F])
let offset = UInt32(bigEndian: data.withUnsafeBytes { $0.pointee })
let date = Date(timeIntervalSinceReferenceDate: TimeInterval(offset))
print(date) // 2099-12-31 23:59:59 +0000
```

If the input is really given as a hex string, not as `Data`:

```
let hex = "BA368E7F"
if let offset = UInt32(hex, radix: 16) {
    let date = Date(timeIntervalSinceReferenceDate: TimeInterval(offset))
    print(date) // 2099-12-31 23:59:59 +0000
}
```

Comment: How can I convert "BA368E7F" to byte array [0xBA, 0x36, 0x8E, 0x7F]

Comment: @Saranjith: See update. – But there should be no need to do so, because the CBCharacteristic.value! is a Data, not a hex encoded string.